# how to make using regex dict with sum of values instead of their overwrite

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I'm new in python. I have a log file with content like this:

```
[14:43:28]Toyota Camry/BH1488XO/service:complex/employee:Oleg/price:550
[15:56:15]Nissan Almera/BE0348CH/service:outside+interior/employee:Serega/price:450
[15:59:44]VW Amarok /BH138E/service:complex/employee:Oleg/price:700
[16:00:48]BMW X7/BH1155HH/service:2-phase complex+plastic /employee:Sasha/price:1400
[16:02:38]Jeep Renegade/BE6782IK/service:wash/employee:Serega/price:300
[16:03:19]MB C300/BT4500BT/service:complex/employee:Sasha/price:550
[16:04:19]MB C200/BT4400HT/service:complex/employee:Sasha/price:1000
```

I need to make a dict which will content an employees as a key and a sum of his prices like {"Oleg": 1250}

i used this code to make lis of employees:

```
    with open ("17082022.log", "r") as file:
        text = file.read()
    emp_list = set(re.findall(r'employee:(.*)/', text))
```

and this to make list of prices

```
    output_pluses = re.findall(r"(?<=price:)[+-]?\d+", text)
```

Comment: Ok so what is your question?

Comment: questions is how to make dict from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with capturing groups to get employee name and price in one step. Next, create a dictionary:

```py
import re

log = """\
[14:43:28]Toyota Camry/BH1488XO/service:complex/employee:Oleg/price:550
[15:56:15]Nissan Almera/BE0348CH/service:outside+interior/employee:Serega/price:450
[15:59:44]VW Amarok /BH138E/service:complex/employee:Oleg/price:700
[16:00:48]BMW X7/BH1155HH/service:2-phase complex+plastic /employee:Sasha/price:1400
[16:02:38]Jeep Renegade/BE6782IK/service:wash/employee:Serega/price:300
[16:03:19]MB C300/BT4500BT/service:complex/employee:Sasha/price:550
[16:04:19]MB C200/BT4400HT/service:complex/employee:Sasha/price:1000"""

out = {}
for employee, price in re.findall(r"employee:([^/]+)/price:(\d+)", log):
    out[employee] = out.get(employee, 0) + int(price)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'Oleg': 1250, 'Serega': 750, 'Sasha': 2950}
```

Comment: Its worked, i was trying to make something like this for a weak. Thank you, you helped so mcuh!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `.split()` function. The advantage is that this way it is not necessary to import the `re` module and use advanced knowledge about designing regular expressions:

```
log = """\
[14:43:28]Toyota Camry/BH1488XO/service:complex/employee:Oleg/price:550
[15:56:15]Nissan Almera/BE0348CH/service:outside+interior/employee:Serega/price:450
[15:59:44]VW Amarok /BH138E/service:complex/employee:Oleg/price:700
[16:00:48]BMW X7/BH1155HH/service:2-phase complex+plastic /employee:Sasha/price:1400
[16:02:38]Jeep Renegade/BE6782IK/service:wash/employee:Serega/price:300
[16:03:19]MB C300/BT4500BT/service:complex/employee:Sasha/price:550
[16:04:19]MB C200/BT4400HT/service:complex/employee:Sasha/price:1000"""

dct = {}
for line in log.split('\n'):
    employee, price = line.split('/employee:')[1].split('/price:')
    dct[employee] = dct.get(employee, 0) + int(price)
print(dct) # gives {'Oleg': 1250, 'Serega': 750, 'Sasha': 2950}
```

The *'trick'* with short `dct.get(employee, 0)` code is that if the `employee` isn't yet in dictionary the value `0` will be returned as price, what is equivalent to `(dct[employee] if employee in dct else 0)` what is then a shortened version of an if-statement going over multiple lines.

Another advantage of using the `.split()` approach over regular expression search is that it will most probably result in a notification with an error message if the lines in the log-file have an unexpected format or content, where the regular expression search approach will just deliver a (wrong) result.

For extremely large log-files the regular expression search approach runs about 10% faster, but for small log-files time required for loading the `re` module makes it much slower compared to the `.split()` approach.

Comment: Or `k,_,v=line.rstrip().partition('/employee:')[2].partition('/price:')`

Comment: @dawg What is `.rstrip()` for in this context and what the advantage of `.partition()` compared to `.split()` ?